# Chakra UI: <Text> with more than 1 word collpasing into 2 lines instead of remaining 100% of content width

Tags: javascript, frontend, chakra-ui

I have an HStack full of Texts and I'd like each to take up exactly 100% of its content. Instead the Texts that have more than 1 word are starting to collapse on itself:

```
<HStack
  spacing={1}
  overflowX={'scroll'}
  className={'hide-scrollbar'}
>
  {traits.map((t) => (
    <Text flex={1} key={t}>
      {t},
    </Text>
  ))}
  </HStack>
```

[image]

Parent is scrollable so even though all 4 won't fit into a single line they should remain 100% each and overflow instead of collpasing.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the text from wrapping, you can simply add the property `whiteSpace="nowrap"` like this:

```
<HStack
  spacing={1}
  overflowX={'scroll'}
  maxWidth="200px"
>
  {["red nose", "blue leg", "yoyoyoy", "hello"].map((t) => (
    <Text key={t} width="full" whiteSpace="nowrap">
      {t},
    </Text>
  ))}
</HStack>
```

[image: screenshot of the example with the fix]